# IF statement : Shell to python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

Lets say

```sh
DIR2 = /tmp/test'
'dirName = stats

if [ -d /$DIR2/$dirName/* ]
```

Above is what I have.
It checks if `/tmp/test/stats` directory contains any files or directories inside of it. 
If it does contain something then I will print out yes.

How can I translate this into python language ?

```
if os.path.exists(DIR2 + "/" + dirName + ):
    print "pass"
```

Is what I tried so far..

But I know I need one more word at the end of the if statement.

Comment: That's not what that shell snippet does. That's not even a valid shell snippet.

Comment: @EtanReisner that shell works totally fine.

Comment: No, it absolutely does not. It doesn't work at all. That first line is not a shell assignment (you have spaces around the `=`). The first line has a trailing single quote. The second line has a leading single quote. The `if` test will cause a `[` failure if there is more than one file in the directory (too many arguments).

Comment: okay i wasn't talking about the declaring. I was talking just the if statement in general and it does work fine

Comment: The if statement **doesn't work**. Try it on a directory with more than one file/directory inside it. You get a `[: too many arguments` error. Seriously, not a single line of those three is correct and valid.

Comment: I just tested by adding one more file into the directory but it still works fine on my case.. I don't get what do you mean by not working.. can you explain why if statement should not work? if thats the case how should i go around it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72693/discussion-between-young-and-etan-reisner).

Comment: Are you using `if [ -d /path/* ];` or `if [[ -d /path/* ]];`? With more than one file/directory in that path the `[` version will throw an error and the `[[` version will simply always return false (because it will test the full expanded name as a single directory). Have you actually tested that on different directories and ensured you got the correct results on them? Because I don't see how you could have. `mkdir -p /tmp/ifdtest/foo; if [ -d /tmp/ifdtest/* ]; then echo "worked"; fi; mkdir /tmp/ifdtest/bar; if [ -d /tmp/ifdtest/* ]; then echo "worked"; fi *error*`.

Comment: So what is the recommended solution for this?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004

Comment: What i simply did is just  if [ -d "$DIR2/$dirName/" ] which is just removing * mark at the end.. it looks like it is working

Comment: That tests whether `"$DIR2/$dirname/"` is a directory not if it has any contents. That is true for empty directories just the same as non-empty directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the easiest way is to check if the list returned by [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) is non-empty...

```
if os.listdir(os.path.join(DIR2, dirName)):
    print("Not empty!")
```

Comment: Unless `os.listdir` is lazy (which it might be I don't know) this is going to be *very* expensive for large directories. Using the first result from `os.walk` is likely much cheaper and consistent.

Comment: @EtanReisner -- True, but OPs original shell code will be very expensive for large directories as well.  Ultimately, I don't know of a platform independent way to check if a directory has some contents...

Comment: @EtanReisner: `os.listdir()` is not lazy; Python doesn't yet have a lazy lister for directories. The OP code is just as inefficient.

Comment: @mgilson does this check for subdirectories and files too? or just what is inside of /tmp/test/stats? I don't want to go beyond /tmp/test/stats/* I just want to see if there is anything inside of /tmp/test/stats/ not like /tmp/test/stats/what/what2/what3 on and on

Comment: @Young -- It only lists the contents of the directory you pass to it.  It doesn't recursively walk into subdirectories like `os.walk`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Shell globbing is likely less expensive than python globbing + list creation. How much less expensive I can't say but potentially substantially.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want without requiring creation of a list with the entire set of filenames in the directory.

```
hasContents = False
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(DIR2 + "/" + dirName):
    if dirs or files:
        hasContents = True
    break
```